# Ubuntu Budgie Live USB with Persistence

Tags: ubuntu, usb

**Ubuntu Budgie Live USB with Persistence**

I need to know if I can run [Ubuntu Budgie](https://ubuntubudgie.org/) on a Live USB with persistence, similar to the way [Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/) can be configured.

For example, if I wanted to make a USB with persistence for Kali, I would just download the .iso file, create 2 empty partitions on a wiped USB (FAT32, and EXT4 labeld "persistence") and run these commands:

```
sudo dd if=kali-example.iso of=/dev/sdb1 bs=512k
```

*AFTER BOOTING FROM USB*

```
mkdir -p /mnt/UUI
mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/UUI 
echo "/ union" > /mnt/UUI/persistence.conf
umount /dev/sdb2 && reboot
```

Now Kali would be setup with persistence. Would the process be the similar for an OS like Ubuntu of Ubuntu Budgie? When I tried to boot from the USB after setting it up similar to the method above, I didn't get as many options for booting as Kali (Obviously I know Kali needs to be more resourceful in that way because of what it was built for). So how can I activate this feature or setup a usb with the Ubuntu Budgie ISO file?

Comment: I used the single ">". There was a typo in the post which I fixed to show the right syntax. Thanks for the spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### mkusb

You can use mkusb to create a persistent live drive with Ubuntu Budgie (and with standard Ubuntu, the other Ubuntu community flavours, Debian and some re-spins and distros that have the same or similar boot structure in the iso files).

Install mkusb from a Launchpad PPA with the following commands in a terminal window,

If you run standard Ubuntu *live*, you need an extra instruction to get the repository Universe. (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu have the repository Universe activated automatically.)

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe  # only for standard Ubuntu

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
```

See the following links for more details.

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

[mkUSB-quick-start-manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=mkUSB-quick-start-manual-12.pdf)

### Do it yourself

The following link might be useful, if you want to make a live drive persistent manually and get in touch with the details behind the scene.

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/diy](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/diy)

Comment: Thanks for the response. The links are very helpfull and I will try this method in few minutes to see how it goes.

Comment: @user296824, You are welcome and good luck :-) Please let us know which method you use and how it works.